# Get decimals of a double?

Tags: c#

I have a function that adds a double to another double but I need to add only to the digits after the decimal point and the number of digits varies based on the size of the number.

```
public double Calculate(double x, double add) 
{ 
    string xstr; 

    if (x >= 10) 
        xstr = x.ToString("00.0000", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo); 
    if (x >= 100) 
        xstr = x.ToString("000.000", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo); 
    if (x < 10) 
        xstr = x.ToString("0.00000", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo); 

    string decimals = xstr.Remove(0, xstr.IndexOf(".") + 1); 
    decimals = (Convert.ToDouble(decimals) + add).ToString(); 
    xstr = xstr.Substring(0, xstr.IndexOf(".") + 1) + decimals; 
    x = Convert.ToDouble(xstr, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo); 

    return x; 
}
```

I'm wondering if there isn't a simpler way to do this without having to convert the number to string first and then adding to the decimal part of it.
As you can see the number to be added to should always be a 6 digit number where ever the decimal separator is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take the remainder of the object divided by `1` you'll get the fractional portion of that number:

```
double remainder = someDouble % 1;
```

To write the whole method out, it's as simple as:

```
public double Calculate(double x, double add) 
{
    return Math.Floor(x) + (x + add) % 1;
}
```

(This is one of those times where you're glad that `%` computes the remainder, rather than the modulus.  This will work as is for negative numbers as well.)

Comment: +1. Note that while answering the title perfectly (and useful for that) it produces different result from OP's code that actually adds numbers in strange way depending on how many digits in whole part: `Calculate(1.1, 1.1)` vs. `Calculate(1000.1, 1000.1)` would give different results.

Comment: The OP's code is attempting to add a value to the decimal part of the number view as an integer then reconstruct the number.

Answer (score 1):

A little more elegant and much more faster:

```
public static double Calculate(double x, double add)
{
    var pow = 5 - Math.Truncate(Math.Log10(x));
    var multiplier = Math.Pow(10, pow);

    var decimals = Math.Truncate((x % 1)* multiplier) + add;
    x = Math.Truncate(x) + Math.Truncate(decimals) / multiplier;

    return x;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this will be much more faster than Servy's?

Comment: @SonerGönül No conversions to and from string.

Comment: @SonerGönül I would certainly expect it to be faster than the OP's code, without testing it, simply because converting numbers to strings and parsing strings as numbers tend to be inherently more expensive than operations manipulating numbers as numbers.  Of course, I'd also expect it to be slower than my answer, simply because it's doing more, and more complex, computations on those numbers.

Comment: @Servy Your answer is not a replacement for the OP's code and do not actually answers the question completely. I have included the code in your answer inside my code :)

Answer (score 0):

So all you want to do is add the fractional part of each value?  Why don't you just do this?

```
public double Calculate(double x, double y)
{
  double fractional_x =  x - Math.Floor(x);
  double fractional_y = y - Math.Floor(y);

  return fractional_x + fractional_y;
}
```

Comment: Why? -because it is not cool looking (or does not look like neat hack) and produces wrong result at the same time. Check results for: `x = -1.4, y = 0` :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another version:

```
public double Calculate(double x, double add) 
{
    return (x - (int)x) + (add - (int)add);
}
```